# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dlopen failed:unknow reloc type35 @8dc77fd4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to load a prebuild native `.so` file in android studio project

```
try {
    System.loadLibrary("torq-demojs");
} 
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

In the app level `build.gradle` I have specified the src dirs

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "x86"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs =['/Users/arpalkumar/torq-native/build/out/jniLibs/android/v8/nativeui/demojs/debug/']
    }
}
```

The directory contains `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folders which contains the `libtorq-demojs.so` file.

Even I have tried to provide the full path like `/Users/arpalkumar/torq-native/build/out/jniLibs/android/v8/nativeui/demojs/debug/x86`
I got the following error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dalvik.System.PathClassLoader[DexPathList..

Still I am getting the error. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you running this on a device or emulator? Is the behavior same on both?

Answer (score 0):

You need have the corresponding ABI for your Android emulators or devices. E.g. if your emulator is **x86_64** architecture, then you need have the `libtorq-demojs.so` file in place of this ABI.

Note that native shared libraries of ABI `x86` may not work for `x86_64` emulators or devices with ABI `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` or `arm64-v8a`.